# Bootstrap left align nav issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am having trouble aligning the logo on my top nav bar.  It works in small view but when I stretch it out the logo moves to the right.  I would like the logo to be all the way to the left and stay there with small or large screens.

I have tried .text-left and pull-left but nothing seems to work.

I am using bootstrap.  Here is my code so far.

Thank You!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TITLE GOES HERE</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #1C2D8E">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="text-left" id="logo" href="#">LOGO GOES HERE</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="../navbar/">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Support</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Help<span class="sr-only">(current)    </span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- JQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's javascript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine? Do you mean it gets pulled in a little bit and isnt fixed to the left?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image is what you try to do I think ?

Comment: yes I would like it to be fixed to the left always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation to hold left use the navbar-brand class.

Replace

```
 <a class="text-left" id="logo" href="#">LOGO GOES HERE</a>
```

with

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">LOGO GOES HERE</a>
```

And remove the wrapping container tag:

```
 <div class="container"></div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TITLE GOES HERE</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #1C2D8E">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">LOGO GOES HERE</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="../navbar/">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Support</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Help<span class="sr-only">(current)    </span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>

  <!-- JQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's javascript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's a little better with .navbar-band but it still slides to the right on a larger screen.

Comment: You want it to be fixed to the left of the screen completely, but still centered in the navbar?

Comment: yes I would like it fixed to the left no matter what screen size but fixed vertically on the navbar

Comment: please see my update commit to the code, simply remove the div container tag you have implemented to move the navbar-brand to the left.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you Chris!!

Comment: You are welcome Ralph! Please select my comment as the answer via the check mark box next to my post if you have found my solution useful.